# How to get the code of a plugin to automate the process in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing

I need to get the code of a plugin (point sampling tool), to automate the process.

I know how to do it in regular tools, using this

```
processing.algorithmHelp('tool').
```

But how can I use it for plugins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In QGIS, navigate "Settings > User profiles > Open active profile folder", then go to `python\plugins\pointsamplingtool`. All process is in `doPointSamplingTool.py` file.